# best practice to replicate MySQL to a non-MySQL database via binlog

Tags: mysql, replication

There are a bunch of tools that read the MySQL binlog, e.g. Tungsten, Maxwell, StreamSets, Debezium, Talend, Attunity, etc... They all require that binary logging is enabled in MySQL, and they read those binary logs as they're being written.

That's fine if you have a brand new database and replicate the data from the outset. I'm curious to know what happens if you already have a lot of data in MySQL, prior to enabling the binlog.

One approach would be to stop the database so no more data is being written to it, copy the data to the target system, enable binlog, and then restart. Going forward, the incremental changes would be appended to the target system which, in my case, isn't MySQL - hence the need for a solution that's can write to databases other than MySQL.

The one concern I have with this approach is downtime. Does anyone have a better recommendation to replicate a MySQL database to another flavor of database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debezium MySQL connector can take an [initial snapshot](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#snapshots) of the captured tables. Once that's completed, it transparently switches over to binlog reading mode. There's no downtime involved, though some locks are taken (usually for a rather short time).

(Disclaimer: Debezium lead here)

Comment: That's a nicely integrated solution. Very helpful. Thanks @Gunnar.